# My application dll's are not properly loaded when launching application through Python Script

Tags: python, dll

I have used the below script to launch my application.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('C:\Program Files (x86)\Terrain\Track3D\TRACK™.exe')
```

I am able to launch the application but a few dll's of my application is not loaded. The application launches perfectly when launched manually.

There are many errors displayed out of which a few are :

1) Failed to load type for modules SchedulesController.
   Error was: Could not load file or assembly 'Schedules.dll' or one of its dependancies. The system cannot find the file specified.
 System.IO.File Not Found Exception.

2) The error window has the title "Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ModuleTypeLoadingException"

Could anyone give me a solution to this problem ?

Comment: where is `Schedules.dll` located in your system? BTW use `raw` prefix for windows paths, you may encounter issues.

Comment: Its located in the Track3D folder. Can you please tell me how I should use the raw prefix for my path mentioned above ?

Comment: can you try that `subprocess.call('TRACK™.exe',cwd=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Terrain\Track3D')` ?

Comment: Hi Jean, I tried the above, but it says invalid syntax. Anyways this was what I used.    subprocess.call('TRACK™.exe',cwd=r 'C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Terrain\TRACK3D')

Comment: did I put a space between `r` and the string? please just copy my line, don't retype it.

Comment: Hi Jean, I just copied the line as you said and ran it. I got the following in the command prompt:  File "D:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 247, in call with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:               File "D:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
   restore_signals, start_new_session)                                                         File "D:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 955, in _execute_child
   startupinfo)                                                              FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: I dont understand where I am making a mistake

Answer (score -1):

A trait of python on windows is forward slashes in paths need to be escaped, and directory or file names containing spaces need to be enclosed in quotes. Further, you have the unicode (tm) at the end of the filename.

```
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call('C:\\"Program Files (x86)"\\Terrain\\Track3D\\r"TRACK™.exe"')
```

The three changes made are:

- Python on windows requires '\\' not '\' in path names
- File / directory names with spaces need quotes
- r"TRACK™.exe" instructs python to use the raw string (to correctly represent the (tm))

Comment: Hi Steve, I tried both these options given by you. The dll's are still not being loaded properly.

Comment: that's not because of that that the DLL cannot be loaded. And backslashes aren't a problem in this particular case since there's no valid escaping sequence following.

Comment: Hi Steve, my application is a 32 bit application. and the TM is a part of the application exe name. So If I was to remove it, it would become an invalid path right ?